# Convert list of byte objects to dict

Tags: python, json, http, python-requests

I'm consuming an API that returns a list a of objects in a JSON. But when I get its content with Requests lib, the content is a byte array of objects like this :

```
b'[{"id":44,"id_string":"a2BPQDsGLfLiwo4r5U4JCY","title":"ED_1803_ITAIPAVA_RJ","description":"ED_1803_ITAIPAVA_RJ","url":"https://kobocat.docker.kobo.techo.org/api/v1/data/44"},{"id":57,"id_string":"a3pb3ALiGuQAHD6XzdHAip","title":"ED_v2018_1801_Taba\xc3\xa7u-SP","description":"ED_v2018_1801_Taba\xc3\xa7u-SP","url":"https://kobocat.docker.kobo.techo.org/api/v1/data/57"},{"id":68,"id_string":"a4Gz2dSwRuyQCsjBwNhf3D","title":"ECS_1804_SONHO REAL-BA","description":"ECS_1804_SONHO REAL-BA","url":"https://kobocat.docker.kobo.techo.org/api/v1/data/68"},{"id":2,"id_string":"a4KjYoy8ieCRNykiYb7nGP","title":"ECS_1708_Vila Esperan\xc3\xa7a-SP","description":"ECS_1708_Vila Esperan\xc3\xa7a-SP","url":"https://kobocat.docker.kobo.techo.org/api/v1/data/2"},{"id":38,"id_string":"a7GQQ7xEu4K6HXWYu9SaSC","title":"ECo_1711_Terra Nossa-UF","description":"ECo_1711_Terra Nossa-UF","url":"https://kobocat.docker.kobo.techo.org/api/v1/data/38"},{"id":78,"id_string":"a7NnnbdhBUSsGoxVWBiGFb","title":"ECoSP_1805_Vila Nova Esperan\xc3\xa7a-SP","description":"ECoSP_1805_Vila Nova Esperan\xc3\xa7a-SP","url":"https://kobocat.docker.kobo.techo.org/api/v1/data/78"}]
```

How can I make it a normal list of dictionares? I tried iterating through the byte array with for in range() , but all I can return are numbers.

Comment: `requests` has a specific method for this. Read [the docs](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/).

Comment: Do you use `requests` to consume the API ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can do this:

```
import json

dic = json.loads(Your_input)
```

Comment: Available from python 3.6 only.

Answer (score 0):

I can't comment to answers so I'm writing here.

```
import json  

dic = json.loads(Your_input)
```

This code works perfectly,

but as @jonrsharpe mentioned in the comment section, you don't need to import anything.

You can use:

```
page = reg.get("your_url")
page.json()
```